# Punctuation marks in math mode in xetex/mathspec

Tags: xetex, punctuation, mathspec

I am using XeTeX and have the following short document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[MnSymbol]{mathspec}
\usepackage[no-sscript]{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setallmainfonts{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}

$\phi, \varphi, \delta \ldots A \vee B$

\end{document}
```

Now no matter what font I am using the punctuation marks in math mode (commas, dots, `\ldots` etc.) come out in Computer Modern. Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the author of `mathspec` forgot to change the mathcode of the comma and the definition of `\mathellipsis`. The following code should do:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathpunct}{\eu@LatinLowercase@symfont}{`,}
\DeclareMathSymbol{.}{\mathord}{\eu@LatinLowercase@symfont}{`.}
\DeclareMathSymbol{<}{\mathrel}{\eu@LatinLowercase@symfont}{`<}
\DeclareMathSymbol{>}{\mathrel}{\eu@LatinLowercase@symfont}{`>}
\DeclareMathSymbol{/}{\mathord}{\eu@LatinLowercase@symfont}{`/}
\XeTeXDeclareMathSymbol{^^^^2026}{\mathinner}{\eu@LatinLowercase@symfont}{"2026}[\mathellipsis]
\makeatother
```

Some other characters or commands might by redefined, this at least solves the problem for the most common ones that are not treated correctly by `mathspec`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74140/4427