# \frac with rounded corners

Tags: rounded-corners, nicefrac

I am overwriting `\frac` code and making it longer and thicker. I am successful so far. Thick frac is better for printing, but it seems sharp on the edges. I want to make its edges rounded. Is there anyone who knows how to do that. Thanks for reading and responding.

My code:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% \frac overwrite
\newcommand{\thickfrac}[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0.8pt}{0}{#1}{#2}}

\newcommand\bigfrac[3][2.0pt]{%
{\thickfrac{\hspace{#1}#2\hspace{#1}}{\hspace{#1}#3\hspace{#1}}}}


\let\oldfrac\frac
\let\frac\bigfrac
% \frac overwritten

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
$$
\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{c} - \frac{d}{\frac{e}{1+\frac{f}{g} } } + \frac{h}{i}
$$ 

\end{document}
```

Output :
[image: sharp edge frac]

Comment: Related: `\mathrule` at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161297/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-mathrule-rounded-endcaps

Comment: I've tried the solution in [161297](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161297/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-mathrule-rounded-endcaps). It requires packages that I cannot use (don't ask why :) ) and I found it too complicated for further maintenance. I will wait my chances for a simpler/light-weight answer that I can compile with xelatex.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. Thicker fraction lines add nothing to clarity and ruin the typesetting.

Comment: @egreg Sir, I agree with you. I expressed myself wrong. My projects final product is first converted into a *.png file and then scaled before print. So lines seem thinner then actual size. You've helped me before about [making +-= bold](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160381/specific-font-for-specific-characters-with-mathspec-package). thank you for that. I made \frac thicker so it seems normal at final print.

Answer (score 8):

While the OP has indicated that he cannot accept this answer because of the packages it uses, I will present it nonetheless to show a practical application of my `roundrule.sty` package.  It is not found on CTAN, but only at the bottom of this answer: [Is there such a thing as a `\mathrule`? (rounded endcaps)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161297/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-mathrule-rounded-endcaps/161309#161309).

Using that package and this MWE below, I first give the OP's original answer (`\thickfracA`).  I then give my answer that only works in `\displaystyle`, known as `\thickfracB`.  Finally, I give an answer that works across math styles, as `\thickfracC`.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel,roundrule}
\stackMath
% \frac overwrite
\newcommand{\thickfracA}[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0.8pt}{0}{#1}{#2}}
% DISPLAYSTYLE ONLY
\newcommand\thickfracB[2]{%
  \setstackgap{S}{2.5pt}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\stackon{#1}{#2}}%
  \mkern2.4mu%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\ht\strutbox-.5\dp\strutbox}{\stackunder{%
    \stackon{\roundrule[-.4pt]{\wd0}{.8pt}}{#1}%
  }{%
    #2%
  }}%
  \mkern2.4mu%
}
% ANY MATHSTYLE
\newcommand\thickfracC[2]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox1=\hbox{$\SavedStyle($}%
  \setstackgap{S}{2.5\LMpt}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\stackon{\SavedStyle#1}{\SavedStyle#2}}%
  \mkern2.4mu%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\ht1-.5\dp1}{\stackunder{%
    \stackon{\roundrule[-.4\LMpt]{\wd0}{.8\LMpt}}{\SavedStyle#1}%
  }{%
    \SavedStyle#2%
  }}%
  \mkern2.4mu%
}}

\newcommand\bigfrac[3][2.0pt]{%
{\thickfrac{\hspace{#1}#2\hspace{#1}}{\hspace{#1}#3\hspace{#1}}}}

\let\oldfrac\frac
\let\frac\bigfrac
% \frac overwritten
\begin{document}
\centering
ORIGINAL\let\thickfrac\thickfracA
\thispagestyle{empty}
\[
x =\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{c} - \frac{d}{\frac{e}{1+\frac{f}{g} } } + \frac{h}{i}
\]
displaystyle ONLY\let\thickfrac\thickfracB
\[
x =\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{c} - \frac{d}{\frac{e}{1+\frac{f}{g} } } + \frac{h}{i}
\]
ANY MATHSTYLE\let\thickfrac\thickfracC
\[
\scriptstyle
x =\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{c} - \frac{d}{\frac{e}{1+\frac{f}{g} } } + \frac{h}{i}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the zoom on the `\displaystyle` answer.

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if the distances and dimensions where the same, that is, taken from `\fontdimen`s.

Comment: @Manuel I wish I knew how to do that. `:^)`

Comment: Neither do I. Anyway, wouldn't it be easier if you actually typeset the `\frac` but overlap the rounded rule? That seems easy and would definitely give the same output as with `\frac`.

Comment: @Manuel I had momentarily considered that approach, but forgot about it.  The one issue I would see with it, is the rule would always be 1 rule thickness wider than that produced by `\frac`, rather than taking up the same width.  But maybe it's worth a try.