# How do I change the way the colon is typeset?

Tags: math-mode, xetex, punctuation, unicode-math, mathtools

In math, I exclusively use the colon `:` for punctuation, i.e. in the sense of `\colon` (compare [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37789/using-colon-or-in-formulas)). Hence I would like to change the way `:` is being typeset, so that it resembles `\colon`.

Is there a way to achieve this in XeTeX / unicode-math?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document} 
$\forall x: P (x)$  using \verb|:|

$\forall x \colon P(x)$ using \verb|\colon|

\def\newcolon{%
  \nobreak\mskip2mu\mathpunct{}\nonscript\mkern-\thinmuskip{\text{:}}%
  \mskip 6mu plus 1 mu \relax}

\mathcode`\:="8000 %
{\catcode`:=\active \global\let:\newcolon}

$\forall x: P (x)$ using revised \verb|:|

$\scriptstyle \forall x: P (x)$

$\scriptscriptstyle \forall x: P (x)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This sends TeX into infinite loop if used along with `\usepackage[french]{babel}`. Anyway, `\number` is not needed after `\mathcode`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for noting both points.  Removed `\number`...don't know how to resolve `babel` issue.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I honestly don't see a difference between `\colon` and your `\newcolon`, though? (:

Comment: Also, it seems the colon now sometimes gets typeset italic (which looks weird), as far as I can tell, this happens in theorem environments where the surrounding text is italic, too.

Comment: On a different note, I just discovered `\DeclareMathSymbol` (see e.g. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74140/xetex-mathspec-punctuation-issue)). Unfortunately, it seems the command requires specifying the font. Does anyone happen to know whether it's possible to use that command in a font-agnostic way to redefine the colon? (Maybe that'd be a solution for French speakers.)

Comment: @balu The difference is only in the default spacing.  What other difference should there be?  As to italic, let me have a look

Comment: @balu As to the italic, changing the `{\text{:}}` in my definition to `{\text{\textup{:}}}` will do it.  However, the 1st version approach of egreg does not suffer this issue, in which you define `\mathchardef\normalcolon=\mathcode\`:` and then replace in my definition `{\text{:}}` with `{\normalcolon}`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I don't actually notice a difference when it comes to the spacing in your examples, that's why I was asking. (Am I blind? :)) As for making the colon non-italic, egreg's solution doesn't seem to work with XeTeX (as he mentioned). The error I'm getting is `Extended mathchar used as mathchar (6300214). [\mathchardef\normalcolon=\mathcode`:]`. In any case, your first solution works! Thanks so much!

Comment: @balu The location of the `:` in my output is different on the first line (using `:`) than it is on the 2nd and 3rd lines (using `\colon` and revised definition of `:`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes, but I what I meant was that I don't see a difference between the second line (`\colon`) and the third line (revised colon / `\newcolon`)? Basically, what I'm asking is why you defined a new command `\newcolon` when `\colon` is already available?

Comment: @balu My understanding was that you were tired of typing of `\-c-o-l-o-n` and wanted to get the same thing by simply typing `:` in math mode.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes No, absolutely. :) I was merely asking why you didn't define `\global\let:\colon` instead of `\global\let:\newcolon` but now I realize that the former causes an infinite loop, so I guess that must have been it.

Comment: @balu That is correct...`\colon` is defined in terms of math `:`, so defining `:` in terms of `\colon` creates an infinite loop.  Here, `\newcolon` is defined in terms of a non-math colon.

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're not French and plan to never write in French, you can just do

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\mathchardef\normalcolon=\mathcode`:
\def\colon{%
  \noexpand\nobreak
  \mskip 2mu
  \mathpunct{}
  \nonscript\mkern -\thinmuskip
  {\normalcolon}%
  \mskip 6muplus1mu
  \relax
}
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\:\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\colon
\mathcode`\:=\string"8000
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$f: A \to B$

$a\normalcolon b$

\end{document}
```

This would send TeX into infinite loop if `babel-french` is used. A safer patch:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\mathchardef\normalcolon=\mathcode`:
\def\colon{%
  \noexpand\nobreak
  \mskip 2mu
  \mathpunct{}
  \nonscript\mkern -\thinmuskip
  {\normalcolon}%
  \mskip 6muplus1mu
  \relax
}
\@ifpackagewith{babel}{french}{% french babel makes : active
  \declare@shorthand{french}{:}{%
    \ifmmode % <--- added
      \colon % <--- added
    \else % <--- added
      \ifFB@spacing
        \ifhmode
          \ifdim\lastskip>1sp
            \unskip\penalty\@M\FBcolonspace
          \else
            \FDP@colonspace
          \fi
        \fi
      \fi
      \string:%
    \fi % <--- added
  }%
}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`\~=`\:\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\colon
  \mathcode`\:=\string"8000
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$f: A \to B$

$a\normalcolon b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can still use `\colon` with the standard meaning. For the colon as relation symbol (what you get normally in TeX with `:`) I provided `\normalcolon`.

**Disclaimer.** This doesn't work with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.