# Defining a character as a macro and preserving its original function

Tags: macros, characters

I would like to redefine a character (say `.`) in such a way that it does its original function and also performs another task (for example runs certain command, say `\mycommand`).

I wrote the following, but it does not work. How I can correct this code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\mycommand{OK}

\catcode`\.=\active
\def.{.\mycommand}%

\begin{document}
Hello.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do it. One is

```
\begingroup\lccode`~=`. \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{.\mycommand}
\catcode`.=\active
```

The `~` will become an active period after `\lowercase` has performed its action, because it only changes character codes and `~` is by default active. The period in the replacement text still has its normal category code, which is permanently attached to it.

However you should *not* make the period active. Any subsequent command such as `\hspace{1.5em}` will raise puzzling errors.

Comment: This approach is so fantastical, I am forced to try to remember it once again.  I was even looking up your prior use of it, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528480/how-do-i-change-the-way-the-colon-is-typeset/528490#528490, when you posted this answer.

Comment: Would you mind if you could also write your original solution (which was as a comment to my question and was deleted afterward) either as a new answer. It could be potentially helpful to users.

Comment: @Name I don't think so, sorry. Activating characters is bad practice in almost every case, unless done in a very controlled way (like `babel` does).