# mathspec percent sign

Tags: math-mode, xetex, mathspec

I am using `mathspec` with XeTeX (`Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019)`), and the percent sign `\%` shows up in Computer Modern (or a similar font) in math mode, rather than the font set using `mathspec`.

There is a previous question – [XeTeX/mathspec punctuation issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74140/xetex-mathspec-punctuation-issue) – showing how to manually add mappings for punctuation characters:

```
\ernewcommand\eu@MathPunctuation@symfont{Latin:m:n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathpunct}{\eu@MathPunctuation@symfont}{`,}
…
```

However, I couldn't find the correct way of referring to the percent sign to be able to redefine it in that fashion – `\%` seems to be the macro `\char"25` internally.

So, in short, how do I get

```
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathfont{…}
…
\begin{equation}
   4\%
\end{equation}
```

to use the glyph from the configured math font?

Comment: it would be easier to test answers if your example code was a real test document without ... that generate errors (it _always_ helps to provide a test document)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add, before `\makeatother` in the code provided at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74159/4427

```latex
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathpercent}{\mathord}{\eu@MathPunctuation@symfont}{`\%}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\%}{\ifmmode\mathpercent\else\symbol{`\%}\fi}
```

Note that nowadays it is not recommended to load `xltxtra`.